# How to convert series index to multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, series

I need to plot a bar chart from a python series data, the series is get from a dataframe below: 
`raw_data.groupby('Age_group')['Survived'].mean()`
`

```
the result of above code is below:
Age_group  
(0, 10]     0.593750
(10, 20]    0.382609
(20, 30]    0.334152
(30, 40]    0.445161
(40, 50]    0.383721
(50, 60]    0.404762
(60, 70]    0.235294
(70, 80]    0.200000
Name: Survived, dtype: float64
```

`I want it to reindex to a multi index series like as below, so that I when I draw the bar chart it will show  y-axis label as the mean number:`

```
Age_group   Mean
(0, 10]     0.593750
(10, 20]    0.382609
(20, 30]    0.334152
(30, 40]    0.445161
(40, 50]    0.383721
(50, 60]    0.404762
(60, 70]    0.235294
(70, 80]    0.200000
Name: Survived, dtype: float64
```

`

To supplement above question, I actually got another multi index series below, and it can be unstacked and plotted to bar chart:

`raw_data.groupby(['Age_group', 'Survived']).size()`
`

```
Age_group  Survived
(0, 10]    0            26
           1            38
(10, 20]   0            71
           1            44
(20, 30]   0           271
           1           136
(30, 40]   0            86
           1            69
(40, 50]   0            53
           1            33
(50, 60]   0            25
           1            17
(60, 70]   0            13
           1             4
(70, 80]   0             4
           1             1
dtype: int64
In [550]:
```

raw_data.groupby(['Age_group', 'Survived']).size().unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=False)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you need:

```
raw_data.groupby(['Age_group', 'Survived'])['Survived']
        .mean()
        .unstack()
        .plot(kind='bar', stacked=False)
```

EDIT: You dont need `MultiIndex`:

```
raw_data.groupby('Age_group')['Survived'].mean().plot(kind='bar', stacked=False)
```

Comment: the data from survived were all 0 and 1s( 0 means dead, 1 means survived), so using mean() function I will get the survive rate, your code here can get the chart successfully but the mean here is categorized by survive state(0 & 1) separately, so the result is not what I want, and the mean data will be 1 and 0 rate.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: my expected output was Y axis shows the mean number, X axis shows the age category, want to check if there is a way that to reindex my current result to a multi index series, thanks a lot anyway,

Comment: I am really confused, why need multiindex? `raw_data.groupby('Age_group')['Survived'].mean().plot(kind='bar', stacked=False)` does not work?

Comment: yeah, this works now, awesome! i didn't click the not useful button. I just getting started on python pyplot, so I wondered how to change a single index series to a multi index series because my multi-index series can unstack and result to a bar chart, the question remains but my problem solved now.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need ?

```
s=raw_data.groupby(['Age_group', 'Survived']).size()

s.div(s.sum(level=0),level=0).unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=False)
```

Update1

```
s.div(s.sum(level=0),level=0).to_frame('mean').reset_index('Survived').set_index('mean',append=True)
```

Update2

```
s
Out[778]: 
Age_group
(0,10]     0.593750
(10,20]    0.382609
(20,30]    0.334152
(30,40]    0.445161
(40,50]    0.383721
(50,60]    0.404762
(60,70]    0.235294
(70,80]    0.200000
Name: Mean, dtype: float64


s.index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([s.index,s])
s
Out[783]: 
Age_group  Mean    
(0,10]     0.593750    0.593750
(10,20]    0.382609    0.382609
(20,30]    0.334152    0.334152
(30,40]    0.445161    0.445161
(40,50]    0.383721    0.383721
(50,60]    0.404762    0.404762
(60,70]    0.235294    0.235294
(70,80]    0.200000    0.200000
Name: Mean, dtype: float64
```

Comment: No but thanks, I want the Y-Axis to be the mean number, not the survived ppl number.

Comment: @JH_EARTH   You can check pivot , also , if pivot you need 3 column rather than 2

Comment: @JH_EARTH check the update ... 1st you need to_frame, then you can set_index with append